# Is it safe to cast between two unrelated types if their structures are similar?

Tags: c++, casting

This is piece of code from our team's small project (acdemic)

```
class B{
public:
 DWORD GetLen(){return i;}
 DWORD i ;
};
class A
{
public:
 DWORD GetLen(){return j;}
public:
 int j ;

};

 B b;
 b.i = 2;
 A * pA = (A *)&b;
 int j = pA->GetLen();
```

"j" will be 2.
Is this code safe? Or, what should I modify it? By using reinterpret_cast or static_cast? or other thoughts?

Comment: [What is your goal](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this code safe?

No.

> What should I do to correct it?

Remove the cast and only call member functions of `A` on instances of `A`.

As for what you should do instead, well, that depends entirely on what you're actually trying to do.

Answer (score 4):

This code is not safe. In C++ use casting operators, e.g.: `dynamic_cast`, `reinterpret_cast` etc.

In this case casting is not allowed, and you're lying to the compiler.

It only works because the classes are essentially identical.